# PHP Spreadsheet Charts - Passing Data Values instead of using Worksheet Data

Tags: charts, phpspreadsheet

I am using the phpoffice/phpspreadsheet for a project and so far it is pretty great.

However, one thing I cannot figure out though is how to pass specific values to the charts instead of using cell values in the worksheet.

I am following this example as a reference: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Chart/33_Chart_create_line.php

Looking at the documentation it should be possible as the DataSeriesValues object does allow for passing null (expected in code) for dataSource and passing a mixed variable (array in my case) as the dataValues parameter. However it doesn't seem to do anything. I just get this:

[image]

**Altered Code:**

```
// Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//     Datatype
//     Cell reference for data
//     Format Code
//     Number of datapoints in series
//     Data values
//     Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues = [

    // attempting to pass values to dataValues parameter
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, null, null, 4, ['12', '56', '52', '30']),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, null, null, 4, ['15', '73', '61', '32']),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, null, null, 3, ['21', '86', '69']),
    
    // original way using the workbook as a data source
    //new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$5', null, 4),
    //new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', null, 4),
    //new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$5', null, 4),
    
];
```

If wondering why I cannot use the workbook values, this is part of a fairly complex project and it would be MUCH simpler to pass values. My alternative I suppose is creating a "dummy" workbook, placing the values there, generating the chart and then place that on the desired sheet.

I have verified that the values I pass are being written here in /Writer/Xlsx/Chart.php, but I see no reflection of this in the chart render:

```
if (!empty($dataValues)) {
    foreach ($dataValues as $plotSeriesKey => $plotSeriesValue) {

        //echo 'value : '.$plotSeriesValue;

        $objWriter->startElement('c:pt');
        $objWriter->writeAttribute('idx', $plotSeriesKey);

        $objWriter->startElement('c:v');
        $objWriter->writeRawData($plotSeriesValue);
        $objWriter->endElement();
        $objWriter->endElement();
    }
}
```

This shows that null values are at least considered for passing as the dataSource param:

```
    public function refresh(Worksheet $worksheet, bool $flatten = true): void
    {
        if ($this->dataSource !== null) { ...
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This wound up being **an issue with Open Office** which is 3rd party Excel software from Apache. For some reason Open Office will not render data sent via $dataValues parameter to DataSeriesValues. Possibly something that could be fixed in the phpspreadsheet library but I doubt a high priorty.

Once opened in actual MS Excel (browser version), it looked fine. However FYI, the base demo uses a "stacked" type line graph grouping. I had to switch it to GROUPING_STANDARD to get the desired results.